# Управление RecyclerView

Tags: android, recyclerview

При загрузке с сети информации в `RecyclerView` помещается по 100 элементов, сделал так что при достижении конца списка загружается еще 100 и так далее.

Но при добавлении новых записей список автоматично сбрасывается на начало списка. А мне нужно чтоб он оставался на месте, и записи просто добавлялись, но ничего со списком не происходило!

**Вопрос:**
*Как сделать так, чтоб `RecyclerView` открывался в заданной позиции (ну или при изменении не бежал в начало )?*

Comment: Приведите пожалуйста кусок кода, того как вы добавляете догрузившиеся 100 элементов в адаптер

Comment: @YuryPashkov, https://github.com/Vitaliy1995/PhotoGallery/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vitaliy/photogallery/PhotoGalleryFragment.java

80 - 90 строчки

Comment: @Maybe_V, не-не, не надо ссылок - добавляйте код в вопрос.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Как сообщает мне мой магический шар, вы, после прихода новых данных, по аналогии с `ListView` вызываете `notifyDataSetChanged()` над адаптером. Отсюда вы и получаете перерисовку адаптера.

Вам же нужно лишь уведомить адаптер о приходе новых элементов так:

```
//до добавления новых данных в список данных измерьте его размер
int prevSize = dataList.size();
//теперь добавьте данные
dataList.addAll(newData);
//теперь скажите адаптеру, что у него новые данные
recyclerView.getAdapter().notifyItemRangeInserted(prevSize, dataList.size());
```

Comment: немного не так! 
Вот код: https://github.com/Vitaliy1995/PhotoGallery/blob/master/app/src/main/java/com/vitaliy/photogallery/PhotoGalleryFragment.java

Comment: @Maybe_V, вы что-то невероятное намутили с переназначением ссылок на список. Вам не надо менять ссылку на список, вам надо добавлять туда элементы. В уже существующий список. Т.е. `list = new ArrayList<>()` должно быть написано всего лишь один раз в коде. После этого не надо ничего другого приравнивать ссылке `list`

Comment: спасибо за помощь !